# Stanford CoreNLP get all edges of a SemanticGraph

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to get a list of all the edges in a given SemanticGraph.
There is ["getAllEdges(IndexedWord gov, IndexedWord dep)" method](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/semgraph/SemanticGraph.html#getAllEdges-edu.stanford.nlp.ling.IndexedWord-edu.stanford.nlp.ling.IndexedWord-) but it seems to only work on a pair of 2 Indexed words, not the whole graph.
Is there another way to get all the edges without traversing the whole graph manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
SemanticGraph parse = ...
for (SemanticGraphEdge edge : parse.edgeIterable()) {
  ...
}
```

There are also parallels of this in `outgoingEdgeIterable` and `incomingEdgeIterable`.

Comment: Do you by any chance know if there is something similar for dependency relationships of the TreeAnnotation? Aka I want to get all the dependency pairs and "dependencies()" seems to return null.

Comment: Is the question how to get dependency relationships from a constituency tree, or how to get the "outgoing edges" in a constituency tree? For the first, I suspect you're best off just converting the tree to a dependency tree, via `SemanticGraphFactory.generateUncollapsedDependencies(tree)`. For the second, there's the `children()` function in the `Tree` class.

Comment: Thanks! I am exploring the options. I have already tried getting children. Will try the factory tomorrow.